# Как вы относитесь к обращению на ты от незнакомцев?

Tags: обсуждение

Собственно, хотелось бы составить общее представление об отношении к данному обращению среди пользователей ruSO для улучшения речевого взаимодействия с его обитателями.

В ответах будут даны мнения для голосования.

## Дополнение

Данный вопрос вызвал весьма ожесточённое противостояние сторонников и противников обращения на ты/вы, но расклад сил оказался следующим:

- Положительно относятся к обращению на ты: 18 (-15 голосов против)
- Отрицательно: 19 (-9)
- Кому всё равно: 31 (-7)

Как можно заметить в 49 случаях из 68 (предполагаем, что один человек один отдал один голос за) можно смело использовать обращение на ты, в частности к тем, кто отметился в обсуждениях как сторонник данного обращения и кто не высказал ярого неприятия данного обращения. Во всех остальных случаях предпочтительнее обращаться на вы, если незнакомец явно не предложит перейти на ты.

## Дополнение 2

Собранные воедино доводы **участников** обсуждений

**Доводы за ты**

- вы - лишняя сущность для обозначения собеседника, ибо уже есть ты.
- вы - устаревшее обращение.
- на ты просят обращаться сами взрослые, начальники.
- вы - усложняет общение, так как требует затрачивать силы на первоначальную оценку для выбора местоимения-обращения.
- если к стороннику обращения на ты обратиться на вы, то он не обидется.
- к Богу обращаются не на вы.
- до 18-го века не обращались на вы на Руси.
- в некоторых языках нет обращения на вы, например в еврейском.

**Доводы против ты**

- можно получить по лицу, ибо это есть проявление неуважения.
- кто обращается к незнакомым на ты, воспринимается как невоспитанный.
- в Сети обращение на ты могут воспринять как неуважение и прекратить общение, либо нагрубить.
- от него избавились в английском языке (thou).

**Доводы за вы**

- на вы это воспитание, уважение и вежливость.
- вы приводится как часть правил поведения в обществе.
- на вы обращаются к старшим, так как у них больше жизненного опыта и посему их следует уважать.

**Доводы против вы**

- правила поведения могут быть пересмотрены
- если к стороннику обращения на вы обратиться на ты, то он может обидеться.
- вы - признак отстранённости от собеседника (вы не из моего круга).
- вы - показатель сословного разделения в обществе.
- вы - обращение к собеседнику во множественном числе.

**Доводы и за ты и за вы**

- можно обращаясь и на ты и на вы сделать это в дружественном или враждебном виде.

Comment: Обсуждения на Мете, всё же, должны касаться самого сайта. А опрос ради опроса, в целом, является оффтопиком даже для Меты.

Comment: Резко положительно. А «вы» в единственном числе надо вообще запретить, нечего лишние сущности в языке плодить :)

Comment: @Sevastopol' конечно не осмелился бы, потому что общество полно глупых стереотипов, отступление от которых будет воспринято как оскорбление. Приходится «выкать», чтобы всякие глупцы, воспитанные со стереотипным мышлением и «традиционными ценностями»™, не обижались

Comment: @Sevastopol' определение степени уважения по форме местоимения — это не воспитание и не уважение, это навязанные обществом глупости какие-то

Comment: Мнения голосования надо делать общими, а то получается накрутка бронзового/серебряного/золотого баджа.

Comment: @Sevastopol' переезжайте в нормальный город, если в вашем за обращение на "ты" может "прилететь".

Comment: @Sevastopol' приводя вот такой пример про "взрослого физически сильного мужчину", который на обращение "ты" будет кидаться с кулаками на спрашивающего и одновременно упоминая "Основы **этикета**" тем самым вводите читающих в заблуждение. Про уважение же мы, edem, вообще молчим.

Comment: @Sevastopol' если там так часто "прилетает", что вы про это уже второй раз пишете, то с людьми там явно что-то не то.

Comment: @Sevastopol' откуда такие предположения? Тем более про **всех**.

Comment: @Sevastopol' опять предположение. Мне всё равно. Просто сомневаюсь, что у кого-то здесь есть сведения обо всех пользователях данной площадки и их жизни вне её. Какое навязывание? Где и в чём?

Comment: @Sevastopol' у вас там пунктик на возрасте что ли? :) дак тут дофига народу за 30 и за 40.

Comment: @Sevastopol' а почему мы, andreymal, должны считать «правила этикета» какой-то непреложной непоколебимой истиной в последней инстанции, которую абсолютно недопустимо корректировать? Вообще, если верить википедии, «уважительное» употребление «вы» появилось в русском языке лишь где-то с 18 века, причём под влиянием французского языка. Зачем нам тут «европейские ценности»™ :)

Comment: @Sevastopol' во-первых, в моей первой школе требования носить костюм не было, и все ходили в чём попало (был ли кто-то в плавках, не помню). Во-вторых, во второй школе я носил костюм, потому что он мне ничем не мешал и почему бы и нет, в то время как половина одноклассников носила что попало, несмотря на требование школьной формы. В третьих, «вы», в отличие от безобидного костюма, добавляет неудобства, внося путаницу с единственным/множественным числом, так что не надо нам тут таких этикетов)

Comment: @andreymal Ну так Вы подойдите ко взрослому человеку. К своему руководителю на работе/учёбе/службе. Вы им тоже говорите "ты"? Родителям своей жены Вы тоже будете говорить "ты"? Что-то я прям очень сомневаюсь. Вы просто используете двойные стандарты. Где Вы работаете, если не секрет? Вы на работу в офис можете свободно прийти в плавках? То есть это действительно для Вас нормально? В любой, уважающей себя, компании Вас выгнали бы в первый же день. Свободная форма одежды допустима, но рамки приличия, тем не менее, даже в этом случае сохраняются.

Comment: @andreymal  И что значит "не надо нам тут таких этикетов"? Давайте теперь будем харкать на улице, материться при детях и бить женщин? Вы - это уважительная форма обращения, причём общепринятая. Это не 2-3 человека во всём мире общаются таким образом, а это есть в абсолютно любом пособии по этикету и по корпоративной этике. И то, что Вы считаете себя выше этого не делает Вам чести.

Comment: @Denis640Kb как вы ловко обсуждение одного несчастного местоимения до битья женщин сводите-то...

Comment: @andreymal Это было относительно фразы "Не надо такого такого этикета". Я пытаюсь донести информацию о том, что есть определённые рамки этикета, и не мы их задавали. Они были сформированы годами. И, если отказываться от каждого из них, ссылаясь на безличность, ни к чему хорошему это не приведёт. Сегодня мы отказываемся от уважительного общения, следующее поколение будет считать, что помочь девушке/маме/бабушке, к примеру, донести сумки - это пережиток прошлого. Затем дружеская взаимовыручка. И так далее. Взрослые все люди. В чём причина не желания быть вежливым? Я не могу этого понять.

Comment: @Denis640Kb как ловко вы сравниваете одну буковку в речи с полезными и вредными общественными деяниями... И кстати насчёт дружеской взаимовыручки вежливо послать на xyz̆ наверное и сегодня все умеют ;)

Comment: При вопросе Google первыми же ссылками ответил [1](https://pbs72.ru/articles/spets-proekty/etiket-dlya-biznesa-vy-ili-ty-/), [2](https://shkolazhizni.ru/culture/articles/30874/), [3](https://www.the-village.ru/village/people/ethics/227797-politeness)...

Comment: @edem Это общепринятый этикет и культура общения. То, что Вы не считаете, что обращение на "ты" является признаком не вежливости - это очень печальный факт. Вы спросили откуда такое мнение. Harry резонно прислал Вам не одну, а несколько ссылок доступно объясняющие откуда берётся такое мнение. Теперь же Вы хотите увести смысл в другую сторону, указывая, что речь про участников сообщества. А что, участники сообщества какие-то другие люди, нежели чем это принято, и нормы морали на них не распространяются?

Comment: @edem Это - принятое в **обществе**. Большом, культурном и воспитанном. Почему мы должны выделять себя из него и пользоваться другими правилами? Обоснуйте...

Comment: Забавно, что сторонники "на ты" называют неопределенную часть противоположной стороны конфликта "глупцами со стереотипным мышлением" и при этом что-то говорят про вежливость :)

Comment: Вопрос бесполезный для сообщества и должен быть закрыт. Кто в этом сомневается может просто почитать комментарии. Если у какой-либо из сторон будут конкретные предложения по работе сайта, то они могут их опубликовать отдельно. Без конкретики это пустое кидание друг в друга тапками.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker если человек считает и говорит одно и тоже, то при чем тут вежливость вообще? Если кому то не нравится сказанное, то сказанное автоматически - невежливо? Вот банально, я считаю, что такой-то человек глуп и говорю об этом. Я  не вежлив теперь? странно как-то.

Comment: Как сказал как-то мне один старый человек (за 80 лет): "Можно общаться очень красиво и выглядеть очень воспитанным в глазах других, но при этом не знать что такое быть человеком". Хорошее воспитание это конечно хорошо, но надо всегда помнить в первую очередь что мы люди и в общении с кем бы то ни было исходить из этого. А "вы" или "ты" это лишь условности, которые приняты в общении в прошлые столетия и скорее всего ещё не раз притерпят изменения в будущем.

Comment: @teran вы можете считать, что угодно, но вас кто-то просил озвучивать свое мнение, критикующее его/ее? Вы на полном серьезе сейчас утверждаете, что назвать человека глупым - это вежливо? Особенно в таком субъективном вопросе, на который априори нельзя дать точный и единственно правильный и, главное, "не глупый" ответ. Или все, кто считают иначе, сразу отправляются в стан глупых и с шаблонным мышлением?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker теперь чтобы не показаться невежливым надо воздерживаться от любых критических оценок, или что?

Comment: @teran назвать человека глупым, просто потому что его **мнение** не совпадает с вашим - это не критика, а ваше **субъективное мнение** по поводу вопроса, на который априори нельзя дать объективный ответ. По такой логике я могу назвать правила стэка и общества "пережитком прошлого" и послать всех неугодных далеко и надолго, назвав их "глупыми", просто потому что **я так считаю нужным**, вот только будет ли мое мнение правильным, а мнение всех остальных неправильным?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Предлагаю назвать эти правила "пережитком будущего" и послать всех.

Comment: @Igor буду честен, после таких бурлений действительно хочется уйти с ruSO и больше не возвращаться.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker same.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Ошибка, спасибо. Я про другое. Но похоже, что тут бестолку что-либо писать, к сожалению.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Последний год не пользовался русским, утратил навык, спасибо за то что возите меня лицом по полу. Постараюсь исправится. Низкий поклон.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Все нормально. Без обид. Сложно придерживатся вашей точки зрения в некоторых ситуациях, но я писал в первом посте не об этом. Беда не в "вы" или "ты", а в человеческом отношении. Обидеть человека больший грех, чем быть недостаточно культурным и т. д. Вот пример. Вынужден общатся по работе с одним человеком на работе, он такой весь воспитанный, только на "вы" и так далее, но может спокойно нагрубить женщине или пожилому человеку. Я об этом. О человечности. А не о всех этих "вы" и "ты".

Comment: @Sevastopol' По какой-то, странной для меня причине, вы решили (хоть там про это небыло написало, по крайней мере явно), что я придерживаюсь той или иной точки зрения. Я сказал про человечность и всё. Но вы раздули тут разговора ни о чём на несколько постов. Культурным быть хорошо, как я писал, вроде там написано на русском (если нет исправьте меня, бывает что путаюсь, так как мало его использую). Я всегда говорю собеседнику чтоб обращался ко мне на "ты" и это ещё в начале разговора, при том что стараюсь говорить так, как собеседнику удобнее.

Comment: С меня корона не упадет если я сделаю так как человеку удобнее, уважив его культурные обычаи, устои или просто подпрограмму в мозге. Это уже мелочи. И если вы считаете что быть человечным, это никак не связанно с данным вопросом, то я считаю что вы не правы, но это мое личное мнение. Тут связь однозначно есть. Пример привел, своего сотрудника с работы, о чём выше указал.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Я вам как грамматический нацист заявляю: "бестолку" хоть писать и неверно, подобная форма встречается в классической литературе не раз и не два, потому совершенно не грешно ошибиться, особенно если ты не профессиональный корректор, знающий на зубок все правила. Проще всего ошибиться тем, кто полагается на зрительную память. Вообще, опускаться до ковыряния в орфографических ошибках в неподобающие место и время — верх бестактности. Смешно слышать из тех же уст нравоучения про этикет. Для пущего эффекта вы б ещё поматерились. Картина маслом: "Севастополь кладёт матом тыкальщиков".

Comment: вопрос заявлен на переоткрытие, а комментария с предложенным обоснованием не наблюдается.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin возможно "Обращение и дружелюбие на площадке ruSO подходит под вопросы для обсуждения на Мета".

Answer (score 38):

Нейтрально.

---

Comment: Вот правильно, из-за слишком тщательного подбора местоимений одни проблемы.

Answer (score 21):

Я бы начал с того, зачем мы вообще с кем то общаемся. Наверное, если мы вовлечены в дискуссию, то эта дискуссия нужна всем сторонам. Ведь если вы участвуете в разговоре, который для вас бесполезен или вам не нужен, то вы впустую тратите время.

Если посчитать, что в общении есть две стороны, и обеим сторонам одинаково нужен этот разговор, то имеет смысл общаться таким образом, чтобы каждой стороне было комфортно. Ведь если вы нагрубите второй стороне, то разговор может быстро прекратиться. Лично я так и делаю в большинстве случаев, особенно в интернете. В интернете много людей и тратить время на грубияна-собеседника просто нецелесообразно.

Поэтому если вы дальновидный человек и ведете разговор с определенной целью, то в ваших интересах общаться так, как собеседнику будет комфортно. Это же работает и в обратную сторону.

Если говорить о разговоре на "вы" или "ты", то я бы предпочел начать на "вы" и только по желанию собеседника переходить на "ты", так как на "вы" скорее всего никто не обидится, а на "ты" многим людям может доставить дискомфорт.

Если принять то, что я выше написал, за правду, то тогда общение на "вы" и потенциальный переход на "ты" (по желанию) дает больше комфорта в общении, а больше комфорта в общении дает лучший результат.

Comment: Больше интересно отношение, если к тебе самому на "ты" обращаются)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica не "к тебе самому", а "к вам самим" >:-}

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я думал, что уже достаточно давно знаю Артёма, чтоб на "ты" общаться )=

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica это сильно зависит от контекста. Тут на сайте с незнакомыми гражданами я предпочитаю на вы, но не испытываю проблем с переходом на ты. С теми, кого не первый год знаю, я бы предпочел на ты. Ппомню как сам перешёл на ты с VladD, мы с ним (и не только с ним) пиво пили в Праге и перешли на ты там, это уже повод для меня перейти на ты с ним в интернете. На игровых серверах, где я админю последние 6 лет, в принципе нет обращения на вы, только ты (в пылу сражения это только мешает), причем там играют и дети и пенсионеры.

Comment: @tym32167 я когда сходку ruSO в Москве устраивал, то там все спокойно сразу на "ты" перешли)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica так пришли поди давно знакомые постояльцы, почему бы и не перейти :)

Comment: @Sevastopol' если вам комфортно перейти с собеседником на ты и ему тоже комфортно, то почему бы и нет. Ну и как я писал выше, на сайте я с собеседниками по умолчанию на вы, по желанию на ты. Мне самому, по большому счету, нет разницы, но я выбрал такую стратегию, чтобы собеседнику было комфортно, чтобы он думал о предмете разговора, а не о том кто к кому и как обращается.

Comment: Здесь надо понимать, что позиция верная, конечно, но абсолютно во всех случаях тыкальщик подстраивается под выкальщика (тыкальщик: "Он обидется, а я могу и на 'вы' говорить, не сломаюсь"), но никогда наоборот (выкальщик: "Не сметь тыкать мне! Я с вашей грязной рожей на брудершафт не пил!"). Вот и получается, что "невоспитанный" тыкальщик всегда и везде следует духу этикета, подстраиваясь под удобство собеседника, а "воспитанные" выкальщики сплошь и рядом нарушают даже первое правило этикета — не учить этикету других.

Comment: @Kyubey по моему опыту все в точности наоборот :)

Answer (score 11):

Поговорим о феномене ты-вы за рамками русского языка.

## "Вы" — это исторический артефакт сословного общества

Нет в местоимении "вы" ни благородства, ни чести, ни уважения. Это слово — лишь мерзкое напоминание о сословном строении общества, когда равенства между людьми не было и в помине, а права и обязанности, возможности и ограничения определялись сословием родителей.

Изначально множественное число использовалось для обращения к императорам и прочим возвышенным персонам, затем постепенно расползлось сверху вниз для обозначения знати и богачей. Динамика была простая: местоимением обозначалось *неравенство*. Выбор как таковой отсутствовал, обращения были чётко регламентированы.

- император-подданный — вы-ты
- отец-сын — вы-ты
- знать-знать: вы-вы
- смерд-смерд: ты-ты

На смену этой чёткой и понятной системе, выпячивающей доминирование и подчинение, пришла система *солидарности*. Хозяин мог выразить уважение, обращаясь к подчинённому на "вы". И наоборот ребёнок мог выразить любовь к родителю, обратившись на "ты". На протяжении веков местоимение выбирал (или позволял выбирать) высший по рангу.

- выбор за высшим по рангу:

  - начальник-подчинённый — вы-вы/ты
  - посетитель-официант — вы-вы/ты
- выбор за низшим по рангу:

  - родитель-ребёнок — вы/ты-ты
  - хозяин-верный слуга: вы/ты-ты

Со временем солидарность стала всё сильнее побеждать. Высшему по рангу уже было не положено выбирать местоимение, дети больше не обращались к родителям на "вы". Стали преобладать следующие соотношения.

- выбора у высшего по рангу нет:

  - начальник-подчинённый — вы-вы
  - посетитель-официант — вы-вы
- выбора у низшего по рангу нет:

  - родитель-ребёнок — ты-ты
  - хозяин-верный слуга: ты-ты

Если наблюдать за современными тенденциями, то ставшее бессмысленным деление на "вы" и "ты" постепенно отмирает, особенно это заметно во французском, немецком, итальянском и других языках. Это объясняется тем, что в современном мире принято считать равенство людей одной из главнейших ценностей, а социальные сети стирают границы в рангах сильнее, чем когда-либо.

В некоторых языках вроде русского несолидарное разделение вы-ты сохраняется, но даже в этом случае происходят метаморфозы: во многих IT-компаниях принято обращение на "ты" вне зависимости от ранга, в молодёжных группах и группах по интересам в большинстве своём обращаются на "ты", и даже в сохранившемся несолидарном разделении взрослый-ребёнок часто можно встретить и вы-вы, и ты-ты. Как уже отметили в другом ответе, деление на вы-ты является для русского неродным и пришло под влиянием французской культуры.

В целом разделение на "вы" и "ты" со временем потеряло всякий смысл и стало чистой формальностью, не выполняющей никакой функции. Со временем местоимение "вы" пропадёт из употребления. Конечно, мы живём сейчас, а не в будущем, и поэтому приходится заморачиваться с местоимениеями, но не стоит обвинять тех, кто выражает всеобщее равенство и дружелюбие по отношению ко всем окружающим, в том, что они кого-то этим оскорбляют.

Если уж на то пошло, то оскорбить переходом с "вы" на "ты" гораздо сложнее, чем переходом с "ты" на "вы" — тогда-то вы точно знаете, что с вами не хотят иметь дела и стараются отстраниться.

## К апологетам этикета

Язык — это вечно меняющееся явление, а не нечто законсервированное во времени. Язык инертен и меняется относительно медленно. Аналогично и с правилами этикета, книжки по которому консервируют абсолютно бессмысленные традиции из прошлого. Например, в подобного рода литературе можно найти рекомендации наклонять тарелку с супом от себя, например.

Вы никогда не найдёте там исследования современных тенденций, и если вы окажетесь среди молодёжи, то это на вас будут смотреть как на психа, когда вы будете отрезать мелкие ломтики мяса от куриной ножки.

Чаще смотрите вокруг себя, разнообразьте потребляемую вами литературу и изучайте предметы со всех сторон. Даже если в вашем доме или в вашем окружении принята какая-то традиция, это не значит, что все "нетакие" спят и видят, чтобы оскорбить вас несоблюдением этикета.

И таки выучите первое правило этикета: не учить этикету остальных.

P.S. Нетерпимость выкальщиков к альтернативной точке зрения видна и в голосах против на положительном ответе: тыкальщики готовы использовать любую форму по желанию собеседника, в то время как обижающиеся на "ты" выкальщики встречаются сплошь и рядом. Учитесь быть терпимее.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Вы совершенно не поняли масштаба изменений. Это изменение всемирное и происходит на протяжении многих поколений, а не в вашем окружении и уже завтра. И учить можно много чему. К вам-то на "вы" обращаться будут, потому что вы будете старичком, верящим в старые устои (как и президент в телеке, который никто не смотрит), и ваши потомки будут знать, как с такими общаться, а вот как все они будут общаться между собой — вы знать не будете, вас в этом кругу общения банально нет и не будет.

Comment: @Sevastopol', удалите все свои комментарии в этом топике, да и ответы тоже. Не позорьтесь ;)

Comment: @Sevastopol' Ну вот смотрите, вы даже не в курсе современных тенденций в медиа: всемирного падения популярности телевидения и старения телевизионной аудитории. Каналы, по которым показывают ВВП, имеют аудиторию 55+ (у некоторых каналов средний возраст зрителя уже до 60 докатился, наверное).

Comment: @Sevastopol', как-то слишком толсто, не находите? :) Если же Вы говорили серьезно, то искренне Вам соболезную

Comment: @Sevastopol', да все, собственно. Но про *одного президента одной страны* и *мир* Вы отожгли, конечно, что говорится, не по-детски :)

Comment: @Sevastopol', бросьте этот толстый троллинг, иначе Вас могут неправильно понять и разгорится локальный скандал :)

Comment: @Sevastopol', судя по Вашей риторике, Вы не шутили, что печально. Что ж, не буду вмешиваться в Ваши проблемы, ибо Вы себя уже сформировали и Вас не исправить :)

Comment: @Sevastopol' https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10166/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2/10189#10189

Comment: @Sevastopol' О боги, о дьяволы! Вы настолько каноничны в почетании политиков этой страны, древних традиций и негнущихся скреп, что вас в пору сдавать в палату мер и весов. Какой смысл обсуждать нюансы этикета в современном мире и всемирные тенденции, если вы раз за разом последовательно отказываетесь хоть немного оглядеться вокруг и ознакомиться с объективной реальностью не по книжкам с пожелтевшими страницами и по сладким речам коррупционеров мирового масштаба из телевизора? Если возникнет желание ознакомиться с реальностью, могу покидать ссылок на материалы по политологии и лингвистике.

Comment: «Выучите первое правило этикета: не учить этикету остальных.» — феерическое самопротиворечие, такое придумать нужно хорошо постараться.

Comment: @defaultlocale Предлагаю вспомнить классический анекдот. *Чем отличается джентльмен по воспитанию от джентльмена по рождению? Одна и та же ситуация. Джентльмен снимает номер в гостинице, входит в ванную, а там моется женщина. Джентльмен по воспитанию: "Мадам, простите-извините, никак не знал и т. д." Джентльмен по рождению: "Простите, сэр. Я, кажется, где-то здесь оставил свои очки".* © народ

Comment: @defaultlocale Суть этикета не в кодировании каждого чиха и следовании инструкции до последней запятой (если, конечно, вы не на приёме у английской королевы), а в комфортном взаимодействии с окружающими. Соответственно, если у вас спросили совета, как повести себя в каком случае, то объяснить традиции будет уместно, а вот если вы на тыкание разражаетесь "Я с вами на брудершафт не пил!" или за столом начинаете всех поправлять "Не хватайте мясо руками!" — это грубейшее нарушение этикета, даже если вы обернёте свою мысль всеми извинениями и пожалуйстами на свете.

Comment: Если человек Вас просит обращаться к нему на «вы», а Вы ему говорите: «Выучи первое правило этикета и не учи меня жить, мерзкий анахронизм», то вы этим устанавливаете какое-то правило этикета, только своего. Если Вы придерживаетесь принципа: «Каждый живет как хочет и не мешает другим», то это интересно, но это уже не про этикет ни коим образом. Этикет сам по себе есть набор правил, который относится как к себе так и к другим.

Comment: @defaultlocale Нет, воспитанный человек в принципе не просит никого подстраиваться под него, он подстраивается сам, соответственно, ответная реакция "нет, я всё равно буду использовать 'ты'" среди воспитанных людей не может возникнуть конструктивно. Разумеется, если человеку вдолбили, что этикет — это пункты от №1 до №189, которые надо выполнять дословно вне зависимости от ситуации ("джентльмен по воспитанию"), то возникают споры. Поймите: нет (и никогда не было) единого свода правил поведения на все случаи жизни.

Comment: Да всё я понял :) Только этикет в моем понимании как раз набор правил. Говорить что смысл этикета в том чтобы не устанавливать правила это странно, все равно что сказать что смысл уголовного кодекса в том чтобы никого не трогать. Об этом и был, собственно, первый коммент.

Comment: А так, проблема с этим холиваром в том, что он заставляет людей занимать какую-то твердую позицию («вы» — значит, устаревшие сословные отношения, «ты» — отсутствие воспитания). Такая позиция не практична: в общении между адекватными людьми вопрос «ты/вы» либо не возникает вообще, либо решается быстро и беспроблемно. Весь спор настолько же лишен смысла как спор о табах/пробелах и разных стилях выравнивания фигурных скобок.

Comment: @defaultlocale Есть УК, есть Конституция. Конституция описывает общие принципы, УК разбирает частности, но если возникает конфликт, то Конституция имеет приоритет. ¶ Если судить по ответам здесь и вообще по моему опыту, жёсткая позиция "я оскорбляюсь на неправильное местоимение" бывает только у выкальщиков. Я, сколько бы ни считал "вы" пережитком прошлого, не могу игнорировать реальность, в которой "вы" — самый безопасный вариант: выкальщикам хорошо, тыкальщикам пофиг.

Comment: Реальность видимо тоже пережиток прошлого :) Не, отличная позиция на самом деле. Если честно я не замечал нетерпимости к «ты/вы» на сайте. Просто когда люди начинаю с лупой разбирать незначительные аспекты этикета у каждого находится мнение. Напомнило: https://twitter.com/iamdevloper/status/397664295875805184

Comment: "А среди вас есть скромные люди?" "Есть! Есть!" "Кто?" "Я-я-я-я!!!"

Answer (score 10):

(Скорее) отрицательно.

---

Comment: @Sevastopol' Вот вам и нарушение вашего CoC, раз уж вы такой блюститель порядка: "Сосредоточьтесь на содержимом, а не на личности. Не используйте слова, _связанные с человеческими качествами_ [невоспитанный] (например, «ленивый»), даже если ими можно описать содержание сообщения."

Comment: @Sevastopol' А ты сейчас оскорбил всех в целом, назвав невоспитанными. На ты обратился специально ;)

Comment: @Sevastopol' если вы считаете, что кто-то из модераторов нарушает правила, используйте [контактную форму](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) для связи с сотрудниками компании. Иначе, попрошу не разбрасываться голословными обвинениями.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Странное противопоставление - "Иначе, ...". Использование упомянутой формы - это возможность, а не обязанность.

Comment: @Igor я в словесные баталии не хочу вступать (: Просто хотел сказать, что не нужно обвинять голословно других участников.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica _если вы считаете, что кто-то из модераторов нарушает правила, используйте контактную форму для связи с сотрудниками компании. Иначе, попрошу не разбрасываться голословными обвинениями._ — уважаю!

Answer (score 10):

> Как вы относитесь к обращению на 'ты' от незнакомцев?

**Скорее положительно**, чем отрицательно или нейтрально.

---

Но это прямо зависит от ситуации, в деловом стиле общения необходимо разговаривать соответственно.
Если же это какое-то сплоченное сообщество по типу SO, то мне больше импонирует обращение на **'ты'**, в не зависимости от возраста или статуса пользователя.

В независимости от сферы деятельности, общение даже на **'вы'** может быть грубее чем на **'ты'**, поэтому осуждать или уже предвзято относиться к человеку только из-за его воспитания или своих ожиданий глупо и бессмысленно.

Я поддерживаю общение любым удобным способом, если только это общение является вежливым по отношению друг к другу. Грубость и невежество со стороны оппонента не приветствуется ни в вежливом общении на **'вы'**, ни в общении на **'ты'**.

Comment: Можно вежливо общаться на 'ты', при этом уважительно относиться к собеседнику, а можно хамить разговаривая на 'вы'. Все SO (и не только) заслуживает уважительного общения между людьми вне зависимости от уровня воспитания или образованности.

Comment: @Sevastopol' , привет, хотел бы упомянуть тебя. Мне лично всегда доставлял только дискомфорт общения на 'вы', в большинстве случаев это было неприятно и моему собеседнику. Мы все одни люди, мы не делимся на взрослых и подростков, мы одно целое, кому-то воспитание не позволяет общаться на 'ты', кому-то нет, но это не должно делить людей на страты. Нужно быть добрее в первую очередь и тогда таких вопросов как этот просто не возникнет. @Qwertiy♦ правильно высказался, он нормально  относится к подобному обращению, потому-что он добрый, нужно быть добрыми всем, тогда и вопросов таких не будет!

Comment: @Sevastopol' почему вы так зациклены на возрасте?

Comment: @Sevastopol' , я это и хотел показать ВАМ, на одном лишь местоимении вы готовы уже вынести вердикт о том, что я не уважаю вас. Я пытался донести до всех, что нет разницы в общении на 'вы' или 'ты', важно уважительно и с добротой относиться. Я специально написал в таком виде, чтобы вы показали различие между добротой и навязанными правилами, независимо от вашего возраста я общаюсь с вами нормально, я не грубил вам, в отличии от вас, вы уже сделали выводы обо мне, хотя я всего-лишь вас упомянул в 'дружеской' форме. Мы все одна большая община, сплоченная обществом SO. Все хотят общаться проще.

Comment: @MoloF К сожалению, это глубокое заблуждение. Сложно назвать сообщество SO сплочённым. Я понимаю Ваше стремление, но, видимо, ввиду Вашего возраста, у Вас несколько другое мировоззрение, чему я крайне опечален. Смоделируем ситуацию. Вы знакомитесь с родителями своей будущей жены. Вы сходу будете называть их на "ты"? Вам действительно кажется, что Вы успеете объяснить им, что Вы делаете это только из самых лучших побуждений. Крайне печален тот факт, что более молодое поколение не обучалось ни этике ни нормам морали, о чём я писал в другом посте. Плохо, что и стремления к этому нет.

Comment: @Denis640Kb , так нет же, я не говорю что это плохо, это хорошо там, где это уместно. Я отношусь уважительно к старшему поколению и обращаюсь на ВЫ. Почему вы думаете что все молодое поколение такое? Я не говорил что я общаюсь со всеми на 'ты', я просто высказал свое мнение. Я не зря показал пример такового общения, я не оскорблял и не относился неуважительно к собеседнику, но он сделал обо мне выводы и при этом подумал что я неуважительно отнесся к нему. Почему вы не видите проблемы в этом? Вы готовы человека считать плохим только из-за того что он 'тыкает'? Почему бы просто не быть добрым?

Comment: @MoloF Он может быть добрым. Как я уже говорил чуть выше - я прекрасно понимаю Ваше стремление. Поймите меня правильно - есть определённые рамки морали, этикета и взаимоуважения. Я писал уже об этом в другом посте, что у текущего молодого поколения просто другой взгляд на взаимоуважение. Я понимаю, что можно дружить, и в этом случае обращение на "ты" это даже хорошо. Но не с незнакомыми людьми общаться на "ты" не культурно, о чём свидетельствуют множество норм этикета. В этом основная суть. Я не вижу никакой разницы между общение в интернете и при личной встрече.

Comment: @Denis640Kb , тогда что нужно делать? Либо все принимают одну сторону, либо всем нужно быть добрее друг к другу. Мы дружно обсудили этот вопрос и каждый выразил свою точку зрения, но вот какой итог? Все остаются при своих мнениях и ничто не меняется? После обсуждения нужно принять решение, но я так понимаю весь холивар закончится именно на стадии обсуждения. Я предлагаю не меняться никому и просто быть добрее. Главнее всего уважительно относится к собеседнику, а потом уже все остальное. Чтобы не получилось как в начале комментариев под этим ответом, когда я ради примера привел такое общение.

Comment: @MoloF Вы отчасти правы. Я полностью согласен с основной сутью Вашего сообщения. Отличие лишь в том, что в реальной жизни люди совсем другие и всегда стараются быть более сдержанными и культурными. Мало кто из тех, кто "ЗА" отношение на "ты" в реальной жизни незнакомому или взрослому человеку будет говорить подобное. Вот я и призываю вести себя в интернете и в данном сообществе в частности так, как эти же люди ведут себя в реальной жизни, и придерживаться моральной стороны вопроса. Правила этикета же не просто так существуют.

Comment: @Denis640Kb я же призываю отвечать на подобное более чем нейтрально, а не съедать человека с ногами и набрасываться на него за его невежливость. В реальной жизни конечно не так, но и мы при общении не видим ни человека, ни его голоса. Все же интернет и реальная жизнь разграничены и нормы этикета здесь опущены, я отношусь положительно к этому, но не поощряю, я просто хочу чтобы все относились друг к другу хорошо и жили в доброте!

Comment: @MoloF Поясните мне, пожалуйста, так в чём же для Вас отличие в реально жизни и в интернете? Вы говорите о том, что в интернете правила этикета опущены. Но в тоже время, Вы же не пишете тем, к кому в реальной жизни вы обращаетесь на "Вы" в интернете на "ты". Вы же не отправляете им смс или e-mail с обращением на "ты". Вы так же продолжаете относиться к ним уважительно. Так почему это позволительно в отношении других людей? Мне кажется, что ни голос человека ни его вид не должны никак влиять на уважительное отношение. Все равны.

Comment: @MoloF *Вы знакомитесь с родителями своей будущей жены. Вы сходу будете называть их на "ты"?* Гм, с родителями что первой, что второй жены всегда был на "вы" и по имени-отчеству. Как и жены с моими родителями. По мне, куда лучше, чем называть ненавистную свекровь/тещу "мамой" и на ты :), что видел у людей неоднократно...

Comment: @Harry , я общаюсь со всеми на 'вы', знаю я этого человека или нет, нет мне разницы. Я просто хотел чтобы все разговаривали более теплее и добрее и не злились только из-за того, что кто-то поменял местоимения местами. Задавайте конкретные вопросы, а не приводите в пример бред, я высказался выше, что нужно искать пути решения, а не настаивать только на своей точке зрения.

Comment: @MoloF Второй, кто ничего не понял в написанном мною... Мда, наверное, надо менять стиль изложения - писать медленно и два раза... :) Даже так: м е д л е н н о :)

Comment: @Harry , мой вопрос к вам. Как можно решить данный вопрос заданный участником SO? Я выслушал вас, вы могли прочесть историю выше. Как решать проблему? У людей даже на SO возник бугурт в отношении друг к другу, что уж говорить про реальную жизнь, когда люди готовы бросаться с кулаками. Это нормальная реакция человека которому 'тыкнули' ?

Answer (score 8):

**"Вы" выражает не уважение, а отстранённость.**
*Вы не такой как я, поэтому обращаться на "ты" я не стану.*

Лично у меня очень мало людей, к которым я обращаюсь на Вы и это обслуживающий персонал (уборщицы, охранники, продавцы), малознакомые люди (живём в одном доме или соседних), бывшие учителя и преподаватели (но **не** начальники). Я ко всем людям по умолчанию отношусь одинаково хорошо и это совершенно не связано с тем, как я к ним обращаюсь. И я позволяю всем обращаться ко мне на "ты".

Находясь на сайте программистов, я считаю, что мы все программисты и у меня нет причин и желания отстраняться от кого бы то ни было, так что автоматически получается обращение на "ты".

А кто не согласен, вот [подходящая история](https://pikabu.ru/story/udobno_li_zhit_po_shablonu_5800763).

Comment: Решил всё-таки ответить, пока не закрыли вопрос.

Comment: До этого сообщения даже не предполагал, что ты реальный человек.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а что особенного в этом сообщении?

Comment: @Qwertiy успел (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, зачем закрыл? :(

Comment: @Qwertiy я закрыл как обычный участник пятым голосом :P

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, все знают что Qwertiy бот (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @Sevastopol', а зачем мне всё население? Население земли 7.53 мдрд человек, вряд ли я общался больше чем с 7.53 тыс, т. е. это 0.0001%. И ещё бОльшая часть оставшегося населения не русскоговорящая, а во многих языках нет двух вариантов обращения. В общем, рассматриваем только русскоговорящих, с которыми я общался. К любому человеку на работе я обращусь на ты, на конференции - тоже, на танцах - тоже. Это основные области общения. Обращения на вы наоборот редки, в большинстве случаев я даже имён этих людей не знаю.

Comment: @Sevastopol', от кого отстраняемся - друг от друга. "Ты такой же как я, мы похожи" - это обращение на ты. Обращение на Вы показывает, что человек другой. Изначально оно предполагало, что он выше (или хотя бы не ниже) по рангу, но потом мутировало просто в отличие в любую сторону. "Говорить "ты" тому, кто отличается от тебя по статусу невежливо, если вы не друзья." По сути так. Но формальное обращение "Вы" при этом является чистой формальностью и реального уважения (которое может быть, а может и не быть) не показывает.

Comment: @Sevastopol', в случае же профессионального сайта, нас всех объединяет то, что мы программисты. Мы здесь не для того, чтобы мериться возрастом, семьями и чем-то ещё. Мы тут именно как программисты. Да, у нас разный уровень в плане программирования, но переносить на него ты/вы было бы полным бредом: ты программируешь лучше меня, поэтому обращаюсь на Вы, а ты хуже, поэтому... тоже на Вы... О, а вот ты - так же как я, сейчас буду "ты" писать. Так не бывает. Поэтому логично исходить из того, что тут все равны.

Comment: Ну и ещё программисты обычно не любят культ карго. Мы же хотим писать красивый код, который отражает то, что он делает. А разве в жизни не так же? Хотим ли мы делать чисто формальные действия, которые ни на что не влияют? Обычно нет. А если "Вы" - это чистая формальность, которая не отражает реальное отношение, то какой смысл её использовать? Обращение "ты" гораздо лучше отражает, что я считаю собеседника похожим на меня.

Comment: @Sevastopol', вроде дописал. Хм.. Что-то я начинаю подозревать, что это надо было в ответ дописывать.

Comment: @Sevastopol', да, а по поводу программистов ещё английский язык свою роль играет. Стандартное приветствие в английском - "hi", а не "hello". А на русский оно переводится как "привет". Выдать что-то в духе "Привет! Скажите пожалуйста, как ..." - вообще криво. Из контекста явно следует, что должно быть "скажи", если обращение к одному человеку.

Comment: @Grundy не только он (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 4):

Задавая вопрос, признаюсь честно, придерживался мнения "(Скорее) отрицательно", почитав же сообщения от других участников и немного поизучав вопрос изменил свои воззрения на этот счёт.

Итак, что мне удалось узнать:

1. Использование "Вы" во множественном числе для обращения к одному лицу "впервые отмечено в латыни для обращения к императору".
2. До 18-го века общение на Руси было исключительно на "ты". Так, в "Повести временных лет" дружина обращается к своему князю: "поиди княже съ нами въ Древляны на дань: и ты добудеши и мы". Опричник Василий Грязной писал царю Ивану Грозному "Не твоя б государскоя милость, и яз бы што за человек? Ты, государь, аки бог — и мала и велика чинишь". Источник: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B
3. Обращение на "Вы" ввёл Пётр 1-й в 1772 с выходом "Табели о рангах". Отныне обращение к "вышестоящему" только на "Вы", за нарушение штраф (ммм, благодатная почва для уважения).
4. Обращение на "ты" в искусстве. В стихотворении Лермонтова "Бородино":
   "— Скажи-ка, дядя, ведь не даром
   Москва, спаленная пожаром,
   Французу отдана?..."

   Обращение "скажи-ка", а не "скажите-ка".
5. Обращение на "ты" в Священном Писании. В главной молитве христиан, данной им Иисусом Христом есть такие слова по отношению к Богу: "Хлеб наш насущный дай нам на сей день". "Дай", а не "дайте".
6. Не во всех языках есть обращение на "вы". В том же еврейском есть только на "ты": ата (к мужчинам), ат (к женщинам).
7. В некоторых же языках, обращение на "ты" исчезло вовсе. Например в английском осталось только обращение во множественном числе вы (You), а местоимение ты (Thou) в единственном числе "устарело" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou

Во всех вышеприведённых примерах обращение на "ты" не является невежливым, неуважительным или оскорбительным.

Лично меня смущает не само обращение на "вы" как таковое, а то, что "вы" это местоимение множественного числа и если к человеку обращаться на "вы", то разумно предполагать, что он по отношению к себе также будет применять местоимения множественного числа "мы", вместо единственного числа "я".

Comment: Отлично подмечено, что местоимение 'вы' использовалось для возвышения вышестоящего собеседника, сейчас это вежливость конечно же, это не плохо, но вариант с англоязычном комьюнити где вместо 'вы/ты' используется 'you' что явно не делит людей на страты как в данном вопросе. Мнения разнятся и люди готовы менять мнения из-за принятия одной из сторон, очень печально что в первую очередь люди не ставят свою доброту, а ставят свою воспитанность и воспитанность собеседника на перед. Не делитесь на страты, сколько людей столько и мнений, нужно всегда оставаться человеком и быть добрым к другому.

Comment: @MoloF you это вы, а не ты/вы.

Comment: Имелось ввиду что нет разделения на 'ты' или 'вы' , а просто всегда используется 'you' как 'вы'. Тогда мы либо все будем общаться на 'вы', либо на 'ты', но такой неприязни я видеть не хотел явно.

Comment: @edem Вы с самого начала были "ЗА", зачем же Вы дезинформируете. И Вы демонстрировали это всем своим видом. Приплыли... 1-2. Ну так и в древности, я извиняюсь, и попу листьями подтирали. Вы же сейчас так не поступаете. Отцы могли законно убивать своих детей. Раньше рабовладение было нормой, для Вам, надеюсь это тоже чуждо. Люди развиваются, и появляются нормы приличия. Это касается не только общения. Чистить зубы, уступать место пожилым и так далее. Ну давайте теперь откатимся на полтысячалетия назад и будем кидаться фикалиями.

Comment: @edem 3. Рабовладение тоже отменили силой и что? Вы считаете, что это было не позволительно делать, только потому, что это не благодатная причина насильно запрещать плохие вещи? 4. Это обращение, обособленное запятыми. И с чего Вы взяли, что это обращение к любому человеку? Как-то Вы странно интерпретируете всё в своих целях. 5. Главная причина, почему мы в обращении к Богу не используем столь искусственные формулы, заключается в том, что мы относимся к Богу как бесконечно любящему нас Небесному Родителю. Вы же маме не говорите Вы?

Comment: @Denis640Kb так вы же сейчас именно этим и занимаетесь - зацикливаетесь на древности. "Люди развиваются, и появляются нормы приличия". Да, люди развиваются, нормы развиваются. Вот только не все хотят меняться и остаются в прошлом. При этом ещё усердно пытаются навязать другим свою точку зрения и клеймят других "невоспитанными".

Comment: @edem 6-7 Никто и не ведёт речь про все языки. В каждой стране свои нормы и морали, что обычно фиксируется в учебниках и пособиях по этике и морали.

Comment: @Denis640Kb "Вы же маме не говорите Вы?" Ещё совсем недавно на Руси к родителям обращались на "вы".

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Это банальные нормы общения. Как же жаль, что Вы с ними не знакомы. Очень рекомендую. Ну так идите и говорите старшим людям "ТЫ". Но Вы этого не делаете. Вы просто используете сейчас двойные стандарты не иначе. И мне лично стыдно за Вас. Особенно учитывая, что у нас подобные модераторы.

Comment: @Denis640Kb жаль, что я столько времени потратил впустую. Глухой да не услышит. Постарайтесь больше не упоминать меня в этих беседах, не хочется больше зря терять время на людей, которые не хотят слушать и способны лишь лелеять и продвигать свою точку зрения.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica О нет, я прекрасно Вас услышал. Просто Вы не первый раз уже сначала говорите одно, а потом пытаетесь подстроиться под ситуацию, отказываясь от своих слов или переиначивая их, как в ситуации с `У меня "ты" и "вы" прямо с уважением не коррелируют. Я принимаю как факт, что у людей разное образование/воспитание.`

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Я имею право упоминать кого захочу. Мы живём в свободной стране. И я Вас не упоминал, именно ВЫ написали мне первый, причём абсолютно неразумные вещи.

Comment: @Sevastopol' у вас удалён всего один комментарий по тревоге от пользователей. Думаю, если вы завтра на него посмотрите, то скажите спасибо, что эту вульгарщину удалили.

Comment: @Denis640Kb как вы тогда можете что-то писать о "воспитании" и т.п, если вот так прямо в лицо плюёте на просьбы других участников? "Мы живём в свободной стране" Свобода одного заканчивается там, где начинается свода другого. Странно, что вас в своё время этому не научили.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Забавно Вы переиначиваете сообщения. Если я Вам скажу - не заходите вообще на `stackoverflow` Вы не будете этого делать? Вы же не станете плевать не просьбы других людей? Просить о вещах ограничивающих свободу - вот это как раз и является плохим воспитанием. И категорически жаль, что Вас этому не научили.

Comment: @Sevastopol' вы видите оскорбления во всём. Я бы порекомендовал вам какое-то время отдохнуть и поразмыслить над всем этим. Вокруг не враги, мы одно сообщество, цель у нас всех общяя. Не следует во всём выискивать злой умысел.

Comment: @Denis640Kb перечитай-те мои сообщения: вопрос и ответы с мнениями и покажи-те где мы были изначально "За" ДО того, как началось обсуждение ко всему этому? Не надо предположений касательно намерений других людей. Если наши слова кажутся неубедительными, то може-те поискать наши предыдущие сообщения с "вы" в качестве обращения. Здесь на Мета, их больше одного.

Comment: @edem Спасибо, у меня уже  была возможность ознакомиться с Вашими сообщениями и вопросами. Хоть, надо признать, что большинство Ваших сообщений на "вы", но мне удалось найти несколько, где Вы обращаетесь к собеседникам на "ты", как один из примеров к `Fat-Zer`. Но даже не в этом суть. А вот то, что Вы изначально имели другую позицию, нежели описываете сейчас ясно показывает Ваше сообщение `А то, что "вы" это множественное число Вас, Денис, не смущает?`.

Comment: @Denis640Kb "перечитай-те мои сообщения: вопрос и ответы с мнениями и покажи-те где мы были изначально "За" **ДО того, как началось обсуждение** ко всему этому?". Не стану скрывать, что такое рьяное *обличение* сторонников обращение на "ты", как невоспитанных, весьма повлияло на мою изначальную точку зрения.

Comment: Лично я отношусь к обращению на "ты" положительно. А вот как раз обращение на "Вы" меня напрягает - причём с обеих сторон. Со стороны собеседника - ну собственно всё уже почти в комментариях сказано, плюс то, что переход с "ты" на "Вы" в процессе общения однозначно воспринимается как непроизнесённое "Вы, батенька, идиот". С моей - да собственно то же самое.

Comment: В английском есть еще такая забавная штука как singular they, но она не особо коррелирует с уважительностью

Comment: @yolosora можно подробнее?

Comment: Бессмысленная аргументация. 70 лет назад все говорили друг другу "товарищ" - почему бы не ввести на том же основании "так было когда-то"? Аргументация из стихов - это уж совсем не по делу, но то и стихи, чтоб ради рифмы все правила нарушать... Есть предложение - к тем, кому комфортно обращение на "ты", именно так и обращаться, кому комфортно на "вы" - обращаться на вы. Например, я вам "тыкаю", вы мне - "выкаете". Устраивает?

Comment: @Harry "но то и стихи, чтоб ради рифмы все правила нарушать" — складывается впечатление, что это не самые любимые книги для чтения у Harry.

Comment: @edem Стихи? да, далеко не самые... В частности и по причине того, что правила языка часто вбиваются в прокрустово ложе правил стихосложения...

Comment: @Harry не припомню такого среди известных.

Comment: @edem Поподробнее: singular they используется вместо he или she, когда неизвестно точно о ком говорят. Пример _If someone has a question **they** can ask_.

Comment: @Sevastopol' 1) Нет, неправда. Поспорить можно со всем. Другое дело, что не всегда можешь быть прав. 2) "Короткие формы обращения в сложившейся русской культуре уместны далеко не всегда." — вывод? Сейчас это так, да, в будущем может быть иначе, особенно если прилагать к этому усилия.

Comment: Коллеги, вас очень интересно читать. Но в процессе обсуждения вы влезли в такой оффтопик, что я бы предложил кому-нибудь перенести это обсуждение в чат (благо такая функциональность есть).

Comment: @VladD "Ну, народ, конечно, собрался. Эксперты. Одни говорят — надкус сделан, другие — нету." М.Зощенко

Answer (score 2):

(Скорее) положительно.

---

Comment: Я однозначно положительно. Мы ж программисты.

Comment: @Sevastopol', мне без разницы, кто ко мне обращается на ты. И под "мы же программисты" имелось в виду не то, что мы грубияны, а то, что между программистами, да и в большинстве IT-компаний принято общение на ты, поэтому в примерно той же среде для интернет-общения переходить на вы было бы несколько странно.

Comment: @Sevastopol' "Но даже он почему-то себе такого не позволяет" странная формулировка. Так говорите, будто использование "ты" - это что-то плохое. Если человек на "ты" обижается, то это его проблема, а не того, кто без всяких плохих мыслей использует "ты".

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Отсылка на введение обращений к персонажу определенного гендера?))

Comment: @Sevastopol', с Эдвардом Сноуденом неудачный пример: в английском вообще нет ты/вы, есть только you (есть некоторые незначительные в данном случае исключения). Уважение передается не через местоимение и форму множественного числа глаголов, а речевыми оборотами.

Comment: @Sevastopol' не знаю, не знаю. У меня "ты" и "вы" прямо с уважением не коррелируют. Я принимаю как факт, что у людей разное образование/воспитание.

Comment: @insolor байка это про "you". Всё там есть. Ты по-английский это thee. Просто добились того, что это обращение изжили. Вы это множественное число, т.е. you, подтверждение этому является глагол-связка "to be" как are, которая используется для местоимений во множественном числе. How **are** you? и They **are** programmers.

Comment: @edem Да нет, в английском было слово thou, а thee это его форма в склонение (вроде как I — me). Было еще thy — твой.

Comment: *Если человек на "ты" обижается, то это его проблема, а не того, кто без всяких плохих мыслей использует "ты".* Точно так же если послали на три буквы, и человек обиделся - то это проблема того, кого послали. Главное, послать без задней мысли ("они не матерятся, они так разговаривают")... Кстати, лично мне даже не так некомфортно, когда обращаются на "ты" ко мне, как самому обращаться на "ты" к другим. Даже к людям, на 45 лет младше :) Так сказать, мое "ты" надо еще заслужить :)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica да, точно, thou. Вы правы)

Comment: @Harry, *мое "ты" надо еще заслужить* -- вот это мне нравится -)

Comment: @Qwertiy программисты на ты, а программисвы - на вы? :)

Comment: @Harry С матом точно такая же проблема. Есть категория людей, которая считает любое употребление мата личным оскорблением всех вокруг в радиусе километра. Вот подходит условный грузчик в порту и спрашивает: "Мужик, у тебя есть закурить? Забыл сигареты, б##". Это что, личное оскорбление будет? Проявление неуважения? Это он так вас лично послал? Он сейчас вам в морду собирается дать? Концентрация бреда, в котором обвиняют всех, кто не следует бессмысленным "правилам этикета", которые созданы по кальке с французского два века назад, превышает все разумные пределы.

Comment: @Kyubey С матом не такая же проблема. "Со двора доносился топот множества ног по гулким доскам, крики, изощренная, разнузданная, *кощунственная* брань." Олег Волков "Погружение во тьму"

Comment: @Igor И что мне должна сказать эта пустая бессмысленная цитата? Тем более с вашим выделением курсивом мерзкого слова, которое в былые времена (да что уж, и в наши тоже) было основанием для преследования невинных?

Comment: @Kyubey невинный кощунник?..)

Comment: @Harry, Прошло 2 года. Ваши слова настолько глубоко задели мои мысли, что за это время, без лжи и преувеличения я достаточно часто вспоминал Вашу фразу "Кстати, лично мне даже не так некомфортно, когда обращаются на "ты" ко мне, как самому обращаться на "ты" к другим. Даже к людям, на 45 лет младше :) Так сказать, мое "ты" надо еще заслужить :)" Вы не только попали в моё мировоззрение, но и привнесли в него новое видение. Я Вам безгранично благодарен за подобный "маневр" на поле дискуссий. Вы смогли в исключительной манере откорректировать мой взгляд на эту ситуацию. Искренне благодарю.

Comment: @Harry, если бы я смог Вас как-либо отблагодарить - я был бы рад.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Один такой комментарий дорогого стоит, так что не беспокойтесь :)

Comment: @Harry, еще раз Вам настоящее, искреннее спасибо! Мое предложение бессрочное ) Вы можете воспользоваться им в любой, удобный для Вас, момент. Рад Вас тут видеть. Мудрый Вы человек.

Answer (score 1):

Нормально - положительно. Сообщество FIDONet, где за обращение на вы «могут и в морду дать» и английский язык, где уважительное обращение идёт из контекста, меня "испортили" ;-).

Comment: Ох, как именно это меня напрягало в Fido...

Comment: @Harry Меня наоборот. :-)

Answer (score -4):

Suvitruf неужели Вам в детстве никогда не говорили, что старших надо уважать? 
Что необходимы быть вежливым.
Что нельзя обращаться на "ты" к незнакомым людям? Неформальное общение возможно с тем, с кем Вы давно знакомы.

> У меня "ты" и "вы" прямо с уважением не коррелируют. Я принимаю как факт, что у людей разное образование/воспитание.

То есть Вы подразумеваете, что у данных людей изначально воспитание проходило таким образом, что их не учили быть вежливыми, не проходили местоимения на уроках русского языка или не изучали разделы формального общения? Ни у Qwertiy, ни у Вас, ни у insolor и так далее?

Или что Вы подразумеваете под "разное образование/воспитание"?
Правильно я понимаю, что все кто проголосовал "ЗА" с лёгкостью могут назвать любого человека на "ты" вне зависимости от возраста?
Это не упрёк, а мне действительно интересно.

И есть ли где-то грань уважительного общения? 
(Например, Вы пожилому человеку без стеснения можете сказать "ты"? Или Вы, без зазрения совести можете общаться на "ты" только к тем, кто младше Вас? Где находится эта грань для Вас?)

Я никогда не смогу ни старшему, ни незнакомому человеку сказать "ты". У меня просто язык не повернётся.

В предыдущем посте Sergey Gornostaev писал :"Видеть грубость в обращении на ты в интернете - это моветон." И многие с ним согласились.

Так объясните мне, чем же на Ваш взгляд отличается реальное общение от общения в интернете? В том, что в интернете Вы можете чувствовать себя защищенным, а потому и рамки приличия соблюдать нет необходимости? Или это так отразились на Вас последствия холивара?
Давайте признаем уже, что сейчас в интернете общаются все. 
И это общение заменяет реальное. Так чем оно для Вас отличается от реального общения? Или Вы с лёгкостью можете написать своему руководителю/учителю/старшему родственнику сообщение на "ты"?
Это ложь и двойные стандарты. 
К тем, кто знаком с Вами в реальной жизни - Вы продолжите уважительное общение даже в интернете, по почте, по смс, и вдругих видах интерактивного общения.

А вот всех остальных, почему то принято обезличивать? Называть на "ты"?
Это в полной мере отражает воспитание человека. И Как я говорил уже ранее, нынешнее поколение считает подобное нормой.

> "Но даже он почему-то себе такого не позволяет" странная формулировка. Так говорите, будто использование "ты" - это что-то плохое. Если человек на "ты" обижается, то это его проблема, а не того, кто без всяких плохих мыслей использует "ты".

Тут я полностью согласен с Harry. 
Если Вам без "плохих мыслей" пошлют на 3 буквы, Вы так же не должны на это обижаться? Ведь это Ваша проблема, а не того, кто Вас послал, получается так?

> И под "мы же программисты" имелось в виду не то, что мы грубияны, а то, что между программистами, да и в большинстве IT-компаний принято общение на ты.

Это откуда у Вас данная информация позвольте поинтересоваться? Где Вы работали, и где было принято общаться на "ты"?
Я стажировался в компании `mail`, работал длительное время в `yandex`, около 4-х лет проработал в ВТБ в ИТ отделе и на текущий момент работаю в ИЦ. 
Ни разу я не сталкивался с тем, чтобы люди свободно общались на ты. Ни корпоративную этику, ни банальное уважение никто не отменял.

У Вас могут быть дружеские отношения с кем-либо, это нормально, но это не означает, что Вы к кому-угодно можете обращаться на "ты". Так же я нигде не встречал на своей памяти отношения из разряда "мы же программисты". 
У молодого поколения, в общении в сети может быть. Когда два подростка почувствовали себя "кодерами". 
Но ни в одной крупной(Да и даже не крупной) компании я не встречал подобного. 
Ни русскоязычной, ни зарубежной.
Я и абсолютно уверен, что это не мне так повезло в жизни, а это банальные нормы общения.

Неважно сколько Вам лет. Неважно какие достижения у Вас были в жизни. Неважно на сколько Вам близок или отвратителен человек. 
Взаимоуважение должно присутствовать.

Comment: А то, что "вы" это множественное число Вас, Денис, не смущает?

Comment: @edem, Нет, меня это не смущает, спасибо, что поинтересовались. Вы это не только множественное число, но и уважительное  или официальное обращение. Более подробно Вы можете прочитать в любой книге по корпоративному общению или этикету.

Comment: "Или что Вы подразумеваете под "разное образование/воспитание"?" Подразумеваю, что люди, обращающиеся ко мне на "ты", делают это не с целью обидеть/принизить. Исхожу из позиции добрых намерений.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Правильно тогда я понимаю Вашу фразу, что люди пишут на "ты" с хорошими побуждениями, но ввиду недостатка воспитания в нормах морали и этикета?

Comment: "Если Вам без "плохих мыслей" пошлют на 3 буквы, Вы так же не должны на это обижаться?" Занятное, притянутое за уши сравнение. Надеюсь, вы не ожидаете на эту гиперболу ответа.

Comment: @Denis640Kb я исхожу из того, что при обращении на "ты" у большинства людей нету цели обидеть. Многие просто не знают/не понимают, что кто-то на такое может обидеться.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica именно это Вы и подразумевали под "разное образование/воспитание"? На мой взгляд это нечто другое, что написано в моём сообщении выше. Что касается 3 букв, то Вы, видимо, не совсем корректно восприняли сравнение. В чём для Вас отличие, если Вас называют на ты, и если Вас посылают без плохих мыслей, на 3 буквы? К примеру Ваш друг посылает Вас на 3 буквы. А теперь представьте, что тоже самое делает незнакомый человек в дружеском стиле. Так в чём тогда разница?

Comment: Если считать, что на ты мы общаемся с друзьями (кстати, о компаниях, лет 30 назад мы организовали свою и лет 20 (пока она не развалилась) все основатели были на ты), то я положительно воспринимаю тут людей, говорящих другим ты. Для меня это значит, что они изначально воспринимают остальных как своих друзей (и такое дружеское обращение на ты в самом деле было принято в начале распространения интернета). К сожалению, все меняется, неизвестного народу в инете стало много, вот и на этом сайте с самого начала приветствовалось -- вы.

Comment: @avp Правильно я Вас понимаю, что Вы с лёгкостью обращаетесь к старшим или незнакомым людям на "ты" в реальной жизни? И ответьте тогда, пожалуйста, на другой мой вопрос. Так чем же в текущий период для Вас отличается общение в реальной жизни и в интернете, когда интерактивное общение почти полностью заменило реальное? С  теми к кому в реальной жизни Вы обращаетесь на "Вы" в интернете Вы пишете "ты"?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, вы меня не совсем правильно поняли. С незнакомыми и малознакомыми людьми (и в реальной жизни и в интернете) я обычно общаюсь на  "вы", что в общем-то должно быть печально (очевидно ведь, что быть друзьями (и следовательно общаться на "ты") было бы лучше)

Comment: Почему-то вдруг вспомнилась судьба (восприятие) слова "товарищ", которое из реально обозначавшего друга ("которыми быть лучше" :)) превратилось просто в обращение, не несущее в себе ничего от того, что первоначально в слово вкладывалось. Ну не могут в большом социуме все быть товарищами, даже если будут обращаться именно так. Исторически сложившееся и действующее в настоящее время семантическое значение "ты" - либо *реальные* дружеские отношения, либо... Например, от гопника в подворотне "вы" не услышишь, но утверждать, что он питает дружеские чувства - было бы преувеличением....

Comment: *неужели Вам в детстве никогда не говорили, что старших надо уважать?* Говорили, говорили. Но сейчас я прекрасно понимаю, что хотели-то на самом деле сказать "возраст, который старше твоего, надо уважать" - именно возраст, а не его носителя. Так же, как сейчас на работе уважаешь должность, а не человека, который её занимает (хотя и последнее не исключено).

Comment: @Sevastopol' "чем старше возраст "носителя", тем "носитель" мудрее, потому что у такого "носителя" жизненного опыта больше." 1) Не пойдёт, взрослым может оказаться вор, пьяница или насильник, и уважать их за возраст и то, что они "многое повидали"? Это шутка? 2) Уважение нужно заслужить. Как на работе повышение. Показываешь достижения? Получай. Нет? Извините.  3) Отсутствие уважение не есть невежливость. ПС. Начальник, значит, это многое объясняет.

Comment: @Sevastopol' *чем старше возраст "носителя", тем "носитель" мудрее, потому что у такого "носителя" жизненного опыта больше.* Увы-увы... бывает, что с возрастом приобретается исключительно возраст - и я даже не могу сказать, что такие случаи редки даже среди знакомых мне людей. *что касается должности, то извините, например вот мои подчиненные* Я в явной форме оговорил возможность такой ситуации. Как и возможность ситуации противоположной.

Comment: @Sevastopol' ну я вот вас не знаю, ни вашу должность, ни ваш возраст, и, по сути, знать мне этого не нужно. Я обычно общаюсь на "вы" по умолчанию, чтобы собеседнику было комфортно, ведь если он предпочитает на "вы" общаться, то мы уже, а если на "ты", то сам предложит и я ничего не имею против. Я знаю людей, которые на 20 лет меня старше, и я с ними на "ты", и знаю тех, кто меня младше - и я с ними на "вы". Это все таки от контекста зависит, а не от возраста/должностей/опыта работы или чего то ещё.