# У модераторов не открывается таймлайн

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, инструменты-модератора, временная-шкала

Не работает [таймлайн](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10166/timeline) по конкретному [вопросу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10166/178988) при попытке открыть его будучи модератором сайта.

Пробовал открывать многократно за последние несколько минут - всегда ошибка. При этом таймлайн вопроса с основного сайта открылся без ошибок, таймлайн другого вопроса с меты - тоже.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: У меня открывается. Т.е., глюк либо локальный, либо временный.

Comment: @Yaant, а ты не модератор - у нас разные таймлайны. У меня по-прежнему ошибка.

Comment: А. да, я потом подумал, что есть еще третья возможность, что это что-то модераторское, но уже поленился дописывать комментарий. :)

Comment: Та же проблема.

Comment: [Задал вопрос на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344615/260198).

Comment: Какая боль быть модератором. То тревоги разгребать весь день. А то вон, совсем ужас, таймлайн не открылся. И ведь я был в шаге от этого. Хехе.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ (ಥ﹏ಥ)